# dynamodb nodejs/lambda date.now()

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to implement TTL (Time to live) in dynamodb and getting unexpected results w/ the time.

my lambda function (nodejs10.x) that populates this database uses the following code for the `created_on` and `code_expiration` fields:

```
  const created_on = Date.now()
  const code_expiration = created_on + (process.env.EXPIRY_MINUTES * 60 * 1000)
```

in my lambda's enviornment variables I have `EXPIRY_MINUTES` set to 2880

looking at https://www.epochconverter.com/ I get the following values for my epoch time ints:

```
created_on: 1569822339715
GMT: Monday, September 30, 2019 5:45:39.715 AM
Your time zone: Monday, September 30, 2019 1:45:39.715 AM GMT-04:00 DST
Relative: 9 minutes ago

code_expiration: 1569995139715
GMT: Wednesday, October 2, 2019 5:45:39.715 AM
Your time zone: Wednesday, October 2, 2019 1:45:39.715 AM GMT-04:00 DST
Relative: In 2 days
```

I'm curoius why when I hover over the record in dynamodb it's showing be a date some 50k years in the future?
[image]

> Do I need to capture the epoch time differently?
>   
>   If I am handling things correctly, will the TTL service read this as 02/10/2019 or 02/03/51721?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const created_on = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0)
  const code_expiration = created_on + (process.env.EXPIRY_MINUTES * 60)
```

Do not convert to milliseconds

Comment: Doesn't `Date.now()` method return milliseconds? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: yep, I realized it as soon as I submitted.

change const created_on to Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000.0) and I'll accept -- thanks

Comment: indeed, "created_on" also needed updating to seconds instead of ms